# How to make shortcut in Deepin to open an application that is on the dock panel?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, deepin, desktop-shortcuts

In Windows, there is a shortcut to open the application that is on the dock panel. For example, `Super + 1` opens the first application, `Super + 2` - second and so on.
Is it possible to do so in **Deepin**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure global shortcuts to "raise or run" any app. The best way I can think of is using the command `wmctrl` like this

`wmctrl -xa Mail.Thunderbird || thunderbird`

This tries to focus on Thunderbird window and otherwise runs the command after `||`. You can see a list of your currently opened windows with:

`wmctrl -lxG`

Comment: While selected as the correct answer, it doesn't _actually_ answer the question asked. The question (to my understanding) was to find out how to run apps based on their position on the dock.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Control Center to add new shortcuts.

[image]

[image]

And there you can add the shortcuts you like; note that Super+1,2 3, etc are already set by default for switching workspace, but you can change that.

(In case you want a short-key for the Control Center itself see [How to create a toggle shortcut for the Deepin Control Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510484/341192).)