# How to create a toggle shortcut for the Deepin Control Center

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, settings, deepin

The Deepin Control Center cannot be launched with a shortcut. It is a panel that appears on the right side of the screen containing all the Deepin settings.

What is the command that could be associated with a shortcut in order to show and hide that panel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen in the file `/usr/share/applications/dde-control-center.desktop`, the `Exec` line is `Exec=dbus-send --print-reply --dest=com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter /com/deepin/dde/ControlCenter com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter.Show`

Using `Toggle` instead of `Show` would better serve our purpose.

So, create a new shortcut with the command

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter /com/deepin/dde/ControlCenter com.deepin.dde.ControlCenter.Toggle
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: by the way, do you know how to add the shortcut to move window to left half or right half?

Comment: @Finn - Do you mean the Control Center window? If so: no. (Also, I am not using this desktop anymore, got back to good old Xfce, and cannot investigate this :))

Comment: I mean the hot key to move the application window like Super + Up to maximize window. It seems not exist in deepin desktop

Comment: @Finn - Please post that as a separate Deepin-window-manager-specific question,  as it is very different from the question above. That would be very useful.  I cannot test now as I said, as I don't even know what is the window manager used by Deepin. I guess it is similar to that of Gnome and Budgie, maybe controlled with Gconf editor. Such keys are said absent here : https://bbs.deepin.org/archiver/?tid-127879.html. **Please post a new question.**

Comment: @Finn: do these work? https://deepinenespañol.org/en/wiki/minitutoriales-and-advice/deepin-keyboard-shortcuts/#espacio-de-trabajo-y-ventanas